# Find the value of $x,y,z$ that minimize $3x^2+2y^2+z^2+4xy+4yz$ under constraint $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1$

Tags: matrices

Find the value of $x,y,z$ that minimize $3x^2+2y^2+z^2+4xy+4yz$ under constraint $x^2+y^2+z^2 =  1 $

i am learning algebra and think a way solve this problem by matrix

Comment: what kind of numbers are $x,y,z$?

Comment: Scalar, but can it be converted into eigenvalue problem?

Answer (score 1):

by Lagrange Multiplier Method we get $$3x^2+2y^2+z^2+4xy+4yz\geq -1$$ and the equal sign holds if $$x=-\frac{1}{3},y=\frac{2}{3},z=-\frac{2}{3}$$